# How to get name and phone number from realtime database in flutter?

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have one user in my database:

```
Users { 
    userId: Xx1j9Pih4BPnu01vnFdMfZqGOr02: {name: 'jack5' ,phone: '0845204281'
  }
}
```

So far I have the following function for getting data from the realtime firebase database.

```
static Future<dynamic> getCurrentUserInfo() async {
  String? userId = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser?.uid;
  final ref = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref();
  final snapshot = await ref.child('users/$userId').get();
  if (snapshot.exists) {
    return snapshot.value;
  } else {
    print('No data available.');
    return '';
  }
```

The function returns an object. How do I convert this object into a string? Or: How do I simply get the name of the current user of my database?

Answer (score 0):

```
static Future<dynamic> getCurrentUserInfo() async {
  String? userId = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser?.uid;
  final ref = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref();
  final snapshot = await ref.child('users/$userId').get();
  if (snapshot.exists) {
    Map<dynamic, dynamic> values = needsSnapshot.value;
    values.forEach((key, values) {
      print(values['name']);
      print(values['phone']);
    });
  } else {
    print('No data available.');
    return '';
  }
}
```

Comment: Thx, but I get error: 'The getter 'data' isn't defined for the class 'DataSnapshot'.' Note that I am using realtime database and not Firestore database

Comment: Now check that. I update the answer

Comment: Are you sure you meant to put in 'needsSnapshot' and not snapshot? if I type in just snapshot, it gives me error -  A value of type 'Object?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'Map<dynamic, dynamic>'.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to get the `name` property of the user, assuming your users are stored by their UID, that'd be:

```
final snapshot = await ref.child('users/$userId/name').get();
print(snapshot.value);
```

Comment: Wonderful, it works. I'm sure you meant print(snapshot.value) instead? Thx

Comment: Yup, I copied the wrong symbol. ;-) Fixed now, and good to hear that it worked.